# Quasar SSR hydration with localStorage issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-side-rendering, quasar-framework

In localStorage there is a "cookies" key, which holds 1 for true and 0 for false to determine if user has accepted the cookies policy (notification popup). User  have to accept the policy so the popup will go off.

But, when I run quasar app in SSR mode, I get an error of hydration once it's rendered.

```js
  import { LocalStorage } from 'quasar'

  export default {

    data () {
      return {
        cookiesAccepted: Boolean(LocalStorage.getItem('cookiesAccepted'))
      }
    },
    // rest of the code
```

and in my component's template tag, I have this code:

```html
      <template v-if="!cookiesAccepted">
        Cookies here
      </template>
    </q-layout>
  </template>
```

in SPA mode it works fine, cookies message is not shown on the page, while in SSR mode, it blinks on the page and I get this error:

[image]

What can be an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any cookies on the server, that's client only, so you could wrap the cookiesAccepted block in `<q-no-ssr>` so it doesn't render on the server.

```
    <q-no-ssr>
      <template v-if="!cookiesAccepted">
        Cookies here
      </template>
    </q-no-ssr>
```

https://quasar.dev/vue-components/no-ssr